# How to check that sub domain is ready to use?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I am creating a subdomain for each user at my service but propagation takes different time...sometimes it faster from PC, sometimes from the server where the site is located...  But I need to send an email when its available from anywhere.. is it possible?

Comment: "available from anywhere" by definition almost impossible to prove. Just send the email after the TTL/Miminum value and add in it a sentence like "your domain will be fully visible everywhere after a few hours/days".

Answer (score 1):

You could trace from the root name servers by using `dig` with the option `+trace` for example:

```
$ dig sub.example.com +trace
```

That could be a good indicator but also check the `SOA MINIMUM` value, that could give you a clue about the estimated time may take to be propagated if is a new record. For existing subdomains, it will depend on the defined TTL.

```
@   IN SOA master.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
    2017030300 ; serial
    3600       ; refresh
    1800       ; retry
    604800     ; expire
    600 )      ; ttl a.k.a. MINIMUM
```

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live / https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308#section-4

> TTL for NXDOMAIN (non-existent domain) responses is set from the minimum of the MINIMUM field of the SOA record and the TTL of the SOA itself, and indicates how long a resolver may cache the negative answer.

Comment: `dig +trace` does not use a resolver, so checking `the SOA minimum` is not needed. This method shows which servers are authoritative for the subdomain and what A record/s they have, but *does not* actually show, if the subdomain is available everywhere as `petriichuk` asked. This depends on the resolvers used (and no using both the +trace and the SOA minimum also does not guaranty that the record propagated. The only way, in my opinion is to check from the locations in question (the server and the clients machine) this does not mean "everywhere" but it's better than `dig +trace`

Comment: The option `+trace` become useful since based on the output you could to find the difference and remaining time your resolvers will need in order to update/refresh and therefore return the desired record, instead of just guessing

Comment: You are right, you will be able to calculate the time the resolver will ask the authoritative servers again, but this is true only when the resolver has asked them already and has cached NXDOMAIN. But what if it did not ask them? You will wait 10 minutes to wait for something that might already happen. And still you are not checking if the record is available, you are just guessing when. In my opinion, since you will be waiting, just wait for 10 minutes, don't run the +trace and SOA checks at all, wait for 10 minutes and then check if the record is available and send the mail.

Comment: `+trace` will just use one arbitrary nameserver at each step so it is far from answering "when it is available from anywhere" which is indeed close to impossible.